# send fax using twilio api php

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am working on Twilio APIs and trying to send fax using Programmable fax but i am getting this error.

> [HTTP 403] Unable to create record: Dialing to this country is not permitted by your account's international permissionsRequest done

Below is my code to send fax.

```
    $sid = config('services.twilio.sid');
    $token = config('services.twilio.token');

    $client = new Client($sid, $token);
    try {
        $fax = $client->fax->v1->faxes->create(
            "+92304xxxxxxx", // to
            "https://www.twilio.com/docs/documents/25/justthefaxmaam.pdf", // mediaUrl
            array("from" => config('services.twilio.phone_number') )
        );
    }
```

Anybody please help?

Thank you.

Comment: What is unclear about _“Dialing to this country is not permitted by your account's international permissions”_ …? The account you are using does not allow sending to numbers in that country … (Since it says “internal permissions”, that is probably something you can configure yourself in your account settings?)

Comment: Country is already enable from settings but still not allowed me to send.

Comment: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181108-How-International-SMS-Permissions-work says you need a “list of countries in which your project allows messaging content to and from” - so if your `from` number is from a different country, you might need to enabled that one as well.

Comment: FYI, I am also using SMS APIs to send messages. it's working fine.

Comment: Did you follow https://www.twilio.com/docs/fax/quickstart? Is the from number you are using _capable_ of sending faxes?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Have you ensured that the country you are trying to send the fax to is selected on your [geographic permissions for voice calls](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/calls/geo-permissions)? Fax is sent over the voice channel not the messaging channel, so even if you can send SMS messages to the country, you may not have given permission for voice/fax yet.